# Parsing JSON in C?

Tags: c, json

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Does Windows have a JSON API that can be called from C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5449197/does-windows-have-a-json-api-that-can-be-called-from-c)
>   [Using JSON data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2352528/using-json-data)

How to parse JSON to an object in C. I know it's easy for scripting languages like Ruby, PHP, etc. They just need to call a simple function (eg. `json_decode($str)` in PHP ) and the `str` will be parsed to a dynamic object or associative array.

What about doing this in C? Are there any examples?

Comment: @Will A nothing is said about Windows development.

Comment: @Radek - true, my bad - am sure there's plenty of choice of libraries on that page tho'.

Answer (score 5):

[json-glib](http://live.gnome.org/JsonGlib) seems to be the best option if you're on Linux. There's [a plethora of other choices](http://www.json.org/) if that doesn't work for you.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to handle JSON in C depends a lot on whether you want to process *abstract, fully general* JSON with arbitrary keys, types, and hierarchy, or whether you're working with data that has a fixed set of allowed fields, types for those fields, and instances in which case nesting is valid. In the latter case, you would do well to make C structures corresponding to the JSON you want to accept, and specialized code to fill those structures. For fully general JSON, you want a general-purpose library (with all the bloat that entails, as well as the performance cost of looking up values by a string key each time you want to access them rather than with a simple `.` or `->` operator).

Comment: is there a such library for general parsing?